# how to manually install logstash-jdbc-output plugin?

Tags: logstash, logstash-jdbc

I cant have internet connection with host.
though I have the whole zip file of the plugin, from git.
so I have to manually install the plugin.
but sadly the git doc doesnt have manual install guide provided.

checked the doc, readme.md in the zip.
did search around for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have a zip format of the logstash plugin. you. can use below command to install logstash plugin.

`/usr/share/bin/logstash-plugin install file:///path/to/logstash-offline-plugins-7.17.13.zip`

Reference : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.17/offline-plugins.html

Comment: oh, I did try it. But it seems it is a command that installs plugin **package**, which means I still have to install the plugin and create the package via logstash to begin with.
So I just installed the package then created plugin package from other machine, then exported package file into a CD then installed it with that command.
Still thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome!